# Set umask permissions new branches on git

Tags: git, centos, branch, umask

I've configured a new git server on CentOS 8. Also, I've installed gitlist for web repo listing using Apache.

My problem is when I create a new branch, permissions are set to rw------- so Apache's user is unable to browse that new branch. I've been looking for umask configuration but I didn't found anything.

I've tried using ~/.bashrc, /etc/profile.d/git_umask.sh with no results.

Is there any way to configure umask on git server for any new branch created?

Comment: The Linux umask is *per process*. Whenever you start a new process, the new one inherits the umask in its parent process. If you want a new Git process to have a particular umask, you set *your* umask, then run Git. If something else is running Git, you'll need to make the something-else set *its* umask before it runs Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first to initiate your local Git repo with:

```
git init --shared=group
```

That would be more reliable than `umask`.

[`git init --shared`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#Documentation/git-init.txt---sharedfalsetrueumaskgroupallworldeverybody0xxx):

> Specify that the Git repository is to be shared amongst several users.
>   This allows users belonging to the same group to push into that repository.
>
> When specified, the config variable "`core.sharedRepository`" is set so that files and directories under `$GIT_DIR` are created with the requested permissions.
>   When not specified, Git will use permissions reported by `umask`.